# Debugging Chrome on Android stopped working after updating to Chrome 39 on desktop

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, adb

Debugging Chrome on my Android has been working great for the last several months, with all the same settings and hardware.

Then today I tried to debug chrome on android from chrome://inspect/#devices and I got a message saying my desktop chrome was too old, and I needed version 39.xx.

So downloaded Chrome 39 (currently beta), and now I get the message "No devices detected".

Not sure how to get debugging back, but I really need it! Tried restarting Windows and Android, no luck.

Desktop:

- Windows 7
- Chrome 39.0.2171.62 beta-m
- Nexus 5 drivers up to date

Phone:

- Nexus 5
- Chrome 39.0
- Android 4.4.4
- Connected as PTP
- Says remote debugging is enabled when I plug in the USB cable.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience today. If you have android sdk installed, try doing an

```
adb start-server
```

or,

```
adb devices
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that ADB was not running in the process list.

Not sure what changed, but I just started the HTC Manager program (I've seen before this starts ADB), and then everything started working again :)

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Thanks,